# Phase of wave is constant

Tags: waves

The general equation of wave is $y(x,t) = Asin(\omega t - kx)$ . We define the velocity of wave using the fact that $\omega t - kx$ is constant and then differentiate with respect to time but it doesn't seem plausible that $\omega t - kx$ is constant . Please explain about it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\omega t - kx$ is constant then $y(x,t)$ is constant.

How do you measure the speed of a wave?

You "measure" the distance a trough or crest or a fixed displacement of the wave, $y(x,t)$, moves in unit time and that is the speed of the wave.

So you have $x$ increasing by $\Delta x$ whilst $t$ is also increasing by $\Delta t$ keeping $\omega t - kx$ constant and find the speed of the wave$\dfrac {\Delta x}{\Delta t}$

$\omega t - kx = \text{constant} \Rightarrow \omega \Delta t - k\Delta x = 0 \Rightarrow \text{speed of wave} = \dfrac {\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \dfrac {\omega}{k}$

Comment: How do we know $wt - kx$ remains constant ?

Comment: When you measure the speed of a wave you measure, for example,  the speed of a crest. A crest is a position where the displacement of the particles of the medium is a maximum ie $y(x,t)$ is a maximum and constant.  If that is so $A \sin(\omega t - kx)$ must be constant which implies that  $\omega t - kx$ is a constant.

Comment: How do we know that the shape of wave doesn't change during propagation ?

Comment: There is only one frequency involved.

Comment: So is there any mathematical proof for it ?